# chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry increase 500 limit

Tags: google-chrome-app

According to the chrome.filesystem [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-retainEntry) there is a limit of 500 fileEntry's that can be retained and restored.

The app I am developing is a document management system that links to local files. Over time I expect that the user will have over 500 links.

Any ideas on how to increase the 500 limit, or an alternative strategy to keep a long lists of local file links ????

Comment: There is no way to raise the limit.

Comment: The docs are slightly confusing. "If the app has the 'retainEntries' permission under 'fileSystem', entries are retained indefinitely.

Comment: You can require the use of openDirectory in the chooseEntry function and that way you can have access to all files in that directory, with no limit.